# How to deploy web app that used .csv file as database in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a web application in python. In my system document, I have a folder that has a .csv file which I use as a database.

What path should I give to access the .csv file? How to create a folder with that file in AWS and access it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What path should I give to access the .csv file?

Use **relative paths**, this way you don't have to worry about the absolute paths to your application. But if you want to use absolute path anyway, your application will be stored in

```
/var/app/current
```